# Type 'undefined[]' is not assignable to type 'number'

Tags: angular, typescript

I started recently to learn typescript + Angular. I am having trouble understang the type assigment in variables. for example I have the following function:

```
    requestBusPoints() {
    //let busName = this.name;
    let buslat: number = [];  

    let buslong: number = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < this.customerSources.length; i++) {

       //busName[i] = this.customerSources[i]._source.name;
        buslat[i] = this.customerSources[i]._source.lat;
        buslong[i] = this.customerSources[i]._source.long;
    }
    var pointLatLng = [buslat, buslong];

    return pointLatLng;
}
```

and I want to use "pointLatLng" into the following block

```
 summit = marker(latlng:[ 46.8523, -121.7603 ], options:{
    icon: icon({
        iconSize: [ 25, 41 ],
        iconAnchor: [ 13, 41 ],
        iconUrl: 'leaflet/marker-icon.png',
        shadowUrl: 'leaflet/marker-shadow.png'
    })
});
```

I thought I could do the following

```
summit = marker(this.requestBusPoints(),...
```

But I got the errors :

Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'LatLngExpression'. 
  
Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type '[number, number]'.

Property '0' is missing in type 'any[]'.

**How can I change the type any[] into [number,number]**

Comment: Use `number[]` instead of `number` in order to address the first error you're getting. As for the lat/long matter. It looks like you're trying to assign an array which contains two arrays to the `pointLatLng` variable. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: Are you trying to pass an `array` of `arrays` like this: `[[lat1, lat2, ...][long1, long2...]]` to the function `marker`? or just one `array` like `[lat, long]` with a lat and long?

Comment: Hi! I am trying just to pass an array like [lat, long]

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean:

```
let buslat: number[] = [];
```

(`number[]` rather than just a single `number`)

If you really only ever have two, use `[number, number]`, but then you cannot assign the empty array as default.

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation on the errors you had:**

Consider this `let buslat: number = [];`

Here, you are defining a variable of type `number`. But you are assigning an array of type `any` to it. Therefore the error.

If you want a number array, you'd do like;

```
let buslat: number[] = [];
```

Similarly for the other array you have.

But, based on your comments and the example in question, here's what you probably want to do:

```
requestBusPoints(): number[] {
    //let busName = this.name;
    let buslat: number;  
    let buslong: number;

    for (let i = 0; i < this.customerSources.length; i++) {

       //busName[i] = this.customerSources[i]._source.name;
        buslat = this.customerSources[i]._source.lat;
        buslong = this.customerSources[i]._source.long;
    }
    return [buslat, buslong];
}
```

Notes:

- buslat and buslong are not arrays, they are just numbers. function
- returns an array of numbers and defined that way using TS syntax
- return statement returns an array of numbers, it does not need a
  variable to assign before it can return the array

Comment: I tried the solution you suggested but, I still have a conflict  int summit = marker(this.requestBusPoints....